# How to create a relationship in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Am new to laravel, I have issues trying to connect this tables: `plans`,`users` and `loans` even after reading the docs,

I have a `plans` tables that have all my plans, then I have a `users` table and `loans` table, my `loans` table has a `user_id` and a `plan_id`, all I want is to pull the records for `plans` and the `users` in the `loan` model.

**Loanplan.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Loanplan extends Model
{
    //
    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'amount',
        'interest',
        'repayment_month',
        'status',
    ];


    public function loan()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\loan');
    }


}
```

my loan model:

**Loan.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Loan extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'loans';
    //
    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'user_id',
        'loanplan_id',
        'payment_made',
        'status',
    ];


    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function loanplan()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Loanplan');
    }    
}
```

I want get all the loan plans  and `users` table records with `plan_id` and `user_id` as foreign respectively respectively in my `LoanController`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with the customization of the `loans` table name in the `Loanplan` model.

According with your descriptions you need the followings setup:

- A `User` can access to one or many `Loan`s

  > `users` 1---m `plans`
- A `Loan` belongs to a `Loanplan` // here I'm using `Loanplan` because that is your model name.

  > `loans` 1---m `plans`

So, this means:

**User.php**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'users';

    //

    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        // 
    ];


    public function loans()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Loan::class);
    }

    //

}
```

**Loan.php**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Loan extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'loans';
    //
    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'user_id',
        'loanplan_id',
        //
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function plan()
    {
        // Notice that here I'm specifying the foreign key:
        return $this->belongsTo(Loanplan::class);
    }

    //

}
```

**Loanplan.php**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Loanplan extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'plans';

    //

    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        // 
    ];


    public function loans()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Loan::class);
    }

    //

}
```

So with this, you can access the information in your `LoanController.php`:

**LoanController.php**

```
public function myCoolMethod()
{
    // get a user
    $user = User::first();
    // access his/her loans
    $loans = user->loans;

    //

    // get a loan plan
    $plan = Loanplan::first();
    // access its loans
    $loans = plan->loans;

    //
}
```

---

I strongly suggest you to read the [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships) regarding relationships and also a course for [database design](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ztHopE5Wnpc). Have a good day mate.

Comment: How do I pass it to the view so I can loop through,  because I want to get the user loan history,.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`Loanplan.php` is missing the `protected $table = "plans"` variable

Same file,

```
public function loan()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\loan');
}
```

the relationship should be hasOne or hasMany, not belongsTo.

Moreover, the name of the class should have Loan with capital L.

```
public function loan()
{
    return $this->...('App\Loan');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to check if the model already querying from table that you created before. Laravel will automatically access table base on your class name.

> Note that we did not tell Eloquent which table to use for our `Flight` model. By convention, the "snake case", plural name of the class will be used as the table name unless another name is explicitly specified. So, in this case, Eloquent will assume the `Flight` model stores records in the `flights` table.

You can read it from [this documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent)

Second, make sure you call the right class. From `Loanplan.php` in the `loan()` method it's not using uppercase for the first letter.

Third, try to state the *foreign key* and *primary key*. You can also check how to do it in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

First of all add `protected $table = 'plans';` to your Loanplan model since the table name is 'plans'

**Loanplan Model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Loanplan extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'plans';
    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'amount',
        'interest',
        'repayment_month',
        'status',
    ];


    public function loan()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\loan'); // or hasMany 
    }


}
```

?>

**Loan Model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Loan extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'loans';
    //
    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'user_id',
        'loanplan_id',
        'payment_made',
        'status',
    ];


    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function loanplan()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Loanplan');
    }    
}
```

?>

add this to the **User Model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
 public function Loan()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Loan'); // or hasMany
    } 
}
?>
```